# set an element visible in a display:none

Tags: html, css

I'd like to fetch an element in a `display:none` block, is it possible ??

For example:

```
<div style="display:none" >
    <h2>hi all</h2>
    <p>abc</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to display the `h2` keeping the parent `div` in `display:none`.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: What do you mean “fetch an element”?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. By definition, all descendent elements of an element with `display: none` are not displayed. To quote [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop):

> ### 9.2.4 The 'display' property
>
> #### none
>
> This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). **Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either**; the element and its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely. **This behavior cannot be overridden by setting the 'display' property on the descendants.**

Answer (score 1):

Using your current HTML this would not be possible. The best thing to do would be something similar to the following

```
<div>
    <h2>hi all</h2>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <p>abc</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve some hidden values you can do using JavaScript. Just add an unique `id` to your element and retrieve it's value. Here's a jQuery way (without any `document.ready()` stuff):

```
<div style="display:none" >
  <h2 id="show_me">hi all</h2>
  <p>abc</p>
</div>

<script>
  element = $('#show_me').html();
  alert(element)

  //Plain JS way would be something like this.
  element_js = document.getElementById('show_me').innerHTML;
  alert(element_js)
</script>
```

You are not displaying per se the retrieved element but at least you are capable of showing it's contents and do whatever you like with it. Actually, I think this would be the closest thing in *fetching* the hidden element.